# connection to database "dbname" failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I created postgres db, import backup, now I want to make new backup from postgres db. This is commands, I had used:

```
createdb -U user dbname

psql -U user -f "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\import\import.backup" dbname

pg_dump -U user -f "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\backups\bobd.backup" dbname
```

After last command I get

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "dbname" failed: FATAL:  password
authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How to fix it? I use the same password for importing db and making backup, why for first case it was ok and for second not?

After modifying file pg_hba.conf (change md5 on trusted) I get error

```
pg_dump: [archiver] could not open output file "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\ bin\backups\bobd.backup": Permission denied
```

Comment: Did `pg_dump` prompt for a password?

Comment: Yes, I enter appropriate, but entered symbols are not shown in cmd

Comment: is you user really called `postgres`?

Comment: yes, it is, I see it in pgadmin

Comment: your commands seem legit. Please double check that you are entering correct username, password and database.

Comment: strange is that for importing pasword was walid, but for backup is not

Comment: I have changed pg_hba.conf for trusted. Now I get error pg_dump: [archiver] could not open output file "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\
bin\backups\bobd.backup": Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by opening command prompt as administrator.
Start - All programs - Accessories - right click on Command Prompt - Run as administrator